# How can I find out, if a WiFi card has two radios?

Tags: hostapd

I have a COMPEX WLE900VX-7A miniPCIe module with an Atheros AR9880 inside and would like to check, if I really can do simultaneous dual band.

Thanks

Comment: You can find specs at a vendor site. `iw list` can give the information too.

Comment: The specs clearly say "simultaneous dual band". I tried `iw list`, but I couldn't find anything hinting at that. For what am I supposed to look for in the output of `iw list`?

Comment: You see there too bands. And they are always "simultaneous".

Comment: Yes, I see "Band 1" and "Band 2".

Comment: So, if they are always "simultaneous", then how do you say, if you want to use both bands at the same time? And how can I check if my card has this capability?

Comment: You can't use both bands at the same time.